# C++ Smooth player - wall - collision (sliding against wall)

Tags: c++, collision, sliding

I already tried to solve the problem of a smooth player - wall - collision so that the player slides along the wall.

I tried following:

```
playerBox->move();
if (playerBox->intersects(wall)) {
    clearMovement();
    movePlayerBoxBack();
}
```

But if the player touches the wall he doesn't slide...
He's just stopping. (I do it separate for W, A, S and D, too.)

It only works if I set the player position back to the
position of the wall he's touching. As follows:

```
player->move();
if (intersect) {
    moveToWall();
}
```

But it doesn't work because for a wall, connected with
another the player touches more sides and the player
jumps to the corner...
So it just works for a single wall...

My question is: how can I make the smooth
player - wall - collision in another way which also works for a wall connected with one or more others.

Answer (score 1):

You could cast a ray out from the player, see if it hits a wall. If it does collide, use the normal of your wall to make a vector that runs along the side in the direction the player is running.

Comment: what do you mean with "use the normal of your wall"?